# ASP.NET: How to get JavaScript variable from popup window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, return-value

This is code for Firefox.

Default.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pop.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Popup" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Hello";
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:InvokePop('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "');");
    }
```

PopupWin.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pop.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnReturnValue" value="Return value back" onclick="ReturnValue();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

pop.js:

```
function InvokePop(fname)
{
    val = document.getElementById(fname).value;
    retVal = window.open("PopupWin.aspx?Control1=" + fname, 'Show Popup Window', 'height=90,width=250,resizable=yes,modal=yes');
    retVal.focus();
}

function ReturnValue()
{
    var newValue = document.getElementById("txtValue").value;
    if ((window.opener != null) && (!window.opener.closed))
    {
        window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = newValue;
    }
    window.close();
}
```

In this case I click button on Default.aspx page and open Popup.aspx as popup window. I enter some value to text box in Popup.aspx and press button. The new value appears in second text box on Default.aspx page.

That works, but how can I pass the new value entered in Popup.aspx page to some handler in Default.aspx page and use it further? For example, I can have another ASPX button on Default.aspx page and when I click it I can use the value entered in Popup.aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do is the following:

Add a hiddenField on the first page. Im calling it "hfPopupValue".

In pop.js u are currently doing this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = newValue;
```

You can change this to:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("hfPopupValue").value = newValue;
```

Afterwards you can just read the value from the hiddenField.
This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using [jQueryUI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), which lets you keep all controls on the same page, meaning cleaner code.

It also doesn't look as nasty as a JavaScript popup window.

Comment: You're right, but I just need this to be solved at the moment.